# Como importar projeto C++ para o VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Sou novo na área de C++, e estou precisando importar um projeto para o VS. Eu só consigo abrir a pasta do projeto, e editar arquivo por arquivo. O C++ não tem um **arquivo.sln** para abrir todo o contexto da pasta, estou muito confuso com o C++ porque ele vários arquivos `.cpp` `.h` e não tem um arquivo padrão para abrir todos, entende? Como vou importar esse projeto com minhas alterações, para depois compilar?

Comment: A noção de projeto e do arquivo que constitui o projeto depende inteiramente do editor. Ha quem programe em c++ sem usar essas noções e compila direto no terminal. Qual o editor em que foi criado o projeto que você quer importar ?

Comment: Estou pegando esse projeto disponibilizado gratuitamente https://www.codewithc.com/c-projects-with-source-code/ especificamente o **Tank Game in C++**

Comment: Olhando assim por alto nesse link, depende muito do projeto. O hangman por exemplo só tem um ficheiro .c que é o de source logo não existe projeto para importar e por isso você pode criar um novo projeto e adicionar o unico ficheiro de source que tem. O pacman por exemplo tem um ficheiro .cbp que é um project file do codeblocks logo você consegue abrir o projeto no codeblocks

Comment: Ok, acho que devo me aprofundar mais nisso! :|

Comment: Repare que esse tank game tem um .cbp também na pasta raiz de `Source Files` logo consegue abrir esse projeto tambem no CodeBlocks. Já testei aqui e quando abro vejo os sources e headers todos direitinhos na estrutura do projeto, e inclusivamente consigo correr sem problema no codeblocks. Só para complementar mais um pouco, esse jogo utiliza a biblioteca [Allegro](https://liballeg.org/) para jogos, que facilita em algumas coisas, quase como um engine

Comment: Encontrei o arquivo, vou baixar o CodeBlock, obrigado!